# How can we cancel an on going API call using redux saga in React Native on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

The test condition is that we are calling 3-4 API's at a time one after another and the API's take time to load a bit. During that time if we press the back button or any other UI component it responds after all the API has been called. So I want to cancel the API on button click.

```
export function* getData(api, action) {
  const { location } = action;
  // make the call to the api
  const response = yield call(api.daily, location);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    // do data conversion here if needed
    yield put(LocationActions.Success(response.data));
  } else {
    const error = errorType(response);
    yield put(Actions.Failure(error));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put up some code ? Can't help you without informations

Comment: Code? I can but that won't be required becuase existing code has least to do. Still, I'll upload a demo code : )

Comment: Sorry i didn't see redux-saga tag. Did you read the doc ? https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html You can yield take an action like a back button press and cancel your current call. If you want to cancel the API call itself, you can cancel your API call through a yield put instead of cancel. If your API is REST you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833178/how-to-cancel-a-rest-api-request

Comment: @hardworker Went through it but the code was not that clear to me so I thought to add a follow up in stack overflow if someone can help. : )

Comment: Use [`race`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RacingEffects.html) to wait for cancel or API response.

Answer (score 0):

The `lodash` library should do the trick:

```
// create debounce
debouncedThing = _.debounce(thing, 1000);

// execute debounced api call
this.debouncedThing();

// onpress button
debouncedThing.cancel()
```

More details on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012922/how-to-cancel-a-debounced-function-after-it-is-called-and-before-it-executes)

See the [lodash library](https://lodash.com/) for more infos about installation and usage.

Comment: I think this won't work in my case. 
debouncedThing = _.debounce(thing, 1000);
This code means that it will make the API wait for 1 sec and then execute. My issue is that the API takes 10 seconds to load. What if the API call has been executed and after 5-second user wants to cancel the call. This won't be appropriate!